# Volatility Plug-ins to investigate packed exe files

Tags: malware, forensics, reverse-engineering, volatility

I am using volatility for malware analysis. I have got a process in my memory image that is packed by malware using UPX packer. Malfind plugin doesn't show injected code for it also.
How can i use volatility plugin i.e volshell to investigate it.

Any comments?

Comment: I would try this question at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/